# What is causing the training time for my model to be so bad?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am using TensorFlow to create a model that can classify plant diseases. I am using `ImageDatagenerator` to read the dataset from the directory:

```
IMAGE_DIMS=(256,256)
# load the images from the directories
train_data = datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir, target_size=IMAGE_DIMS, batch_size=100, class_mode="categorical", color_mode="rgb", shuffle=True)
valid_data = datagen.flow_from_directory(valid_dir, target_size=IMAGE_DIMS, batch_size=100, class_mode="categorical", color_mode="rgb", shuffle=True)
```

This is how I am defining my model:

```
# load pre-trained model
pre_trained_model = InceptionV3(input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE, include_top=False)
for layer in pre_trained_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
last_layer = pre_trained_model.get_layer('mixed7').output

# create untrained model using functional API
x = keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation="relu", name="CONV-TRAINABLE-1")(last_layer)
x = keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2)(x)
x = keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation="relu", name="CONV-TRAINABLE-2")(x)
x = keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name="NORM-TRAINAABLE")(x)
x = keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu", name="DENSE_1")(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu", name="DENSE_2")(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name="DENSE_3")(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(NUM_OUTPUT_LAYER, activation="softmax", name="OUTPUT_LAYER")(x)

model = keras.Model(pre_trained_model.input, x)
model.compile(
    optimizer="adam",
    loss="categorical_crossentropy",
    metrics=["accuracy"]
)
```

**NOTE THAT I AM MAKING ALL THE LAYERS IN THE INCEPTION MODEL AS UNTRAINABLE**

By running `model.summary()`, this is what I get in for the parameter summary:

```
Total params: 9,265,590
Trainable params: 290,262
Non-trainable params: 8,975,328
```

When I try to run `model.fit()`, the ETA time for the epoch is >20hrs/epoch. **I ran the same code about 2-3 months ago, and at that time, the ETA wasn't as high as seen (I don't completely recall but I think it was somewhere about 20min/epoch)**. Given the context that trainable params are ~300,000, >20hrs seems too much in my opinion. **Note that I have a GPU setup (RTX 2060) in Windows and I have setup cuDNN and CUDA tool kit properly, there are no CUDA errors.**

I have changing the batch size and other parameters, and nothing seems to work.

I am also running in the beginning, but I don't know if this will help.

```
#config GPU to not cause any error while training
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession

config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)
```

I also tried running the same code in a different machine without any GPU and a different CPU, and the ETA is similar there also.

Edit: I am seeing that dedicated GPU memory is being occupied but there is no GPU boost being applied to the core or the memory, and also there s no GPU usage.
[image: Screen Shot of MSI dragon center]
Generally, it shows here (MSI dragon center) how much GPU is being used when any DNN is training.

Software version:
WINDOWS 11
Python: 3.8.7
TensorFlow: 2.4.0
CUDA: 11.0
cuDNN: 8.1

What could be the possible reasons for this behavior?

Comment: And so how much of GPU is used? Maybe it overheats?

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov no overheating, the screenshot is the current problem, i.e., no GPU usage

Comment: nvidia-smi is your friend. Run it while doing your job. If your GPU utilization is zero, but the TF process is taking up lots of GPU ram, then that's pretty odd. It's probably nothing to do with your model but something about your usage of tf1. See if you can get a pure tf2 model training with GPU to ensure that the CUDA drivers are good.

Comment: @Yaoshiang thanks for your reply, i will certainly try the nvidia smi, I am anyway going to uninstall all of CUDA and tensorflow and redo the installation.